# Exact match for string using XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, exact-match

I wrote an xpath to scrape elements from a web page using selenium c#.

Here is the XPath

```
tbody/tr[@backcolor]/td/b/a[contains(text(),"match text")]
```

This is working fine until I found duplicates coming for `match text`. So, on a web page I've two elements with the `match text`

one with `match text` and the other with `match text 9000`

Now, I only need to perform clicking for `match text`. So, I wrote the following XPath

```
table/tbody/tr[@bgcolor]/td/b/a[text()="   match text"]
```

Note that the match text has leading spaces on the web page. The above Xpath didn't worked. I've checked this with `Fire Path` extension for Firefox.

Can anyone suggest me a Xpath, which finds the exact match for the `match text`. Assume that the match text can contain any number of leading spaces.

I've also tried using the `normalize-space()` but that didn't work either. This is what I've tried

```
text()[normalize-space(.)='match']
```

I found some questions on SO, which didn't help.

Appreciate your help.

**Update:**

Thanks for your answers but none of them worked for me.

Also I've mentioned these two strings

- match text
- match text 9000

In my code I'll be iterating them over foreach loop. So, I cannot guarantee that I'll get 9000 as the second element.

I've tried all the answers mentioned using FirePath extension for Firefox, but nothing is selected on the web page.

As mentioned earlier I've leading spaces before the match text.

**HTML:** (To match the xpath)

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><b><a class="s7intext" href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp; match text</a></b></td></tr>
<tr><td><b><a class="s7intext" href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp; match text random</a></b></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML in my page, which has `&nbsp;` characters. There are two `&nbsp;` characters and an additional space before `match text`. The site that I'm scraping the elements is a client site. I cannot say him to modify his HTML on it.

Comment: "I've also tried using the normalize-space() but that didn't work either." (1) What exactly did you try, with normalize-space()? (2) When you say things didn't work, what actually happened? Did the XPath expression select nothing? Was there an error message?

Comment: At some stage you have modified the question so your input now includes non-breaking space characters. This means that all answers prior to that edit will no longer work. Changing the question in such a fundamental way leads to great confusion and it's much better to start a new question. normalize-space() strips "whitespace"; for this purpose non-breaking spaces are not considered to be whitespace. To strip them, use the translate() function.

Answer (score 2):

One of these 2 options should work given that your XPath which using `contains()` worked :

```
tbody/tr[@backcolor]/td/b/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'match text']

tbody/tr[@backcolor]/td/b/a[text()[normalize-space(.) = 'match text']]
```

Input HTML for test :

```
<div>
    <a>
       match text 900</a>
    <a>
       match text</a>
</div>
```

XPath expressions tested :

```
//a[normalize-space(text()) = 'match text']

//a[text()[normalize-space(.) = 'match text']]
```

The output is always only the 2nd `<a>` element (I tested [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), you can use any other tester of choice). If none of these worked, please provide a simplified HTML markup that is failing against the XPath.

**UPDATE :**

According to the HTML snippet posted in the update, it is clear why `normalize-space()` didn't work. I'd suggest a different approach then. In XPath 2.0 you can use `ends-with()` function to match `<a>` having inner text ends with `'match text'` like so :

```
//a[ends-with(.,'match text')]
```

In case Selenium doesn't support XPath 2.0, you can simulate `ends-with()` in XPath 1.0 like so :

```
//a[substring(., string-length(.)-string-length('match text')+1) = 'match text']
```

Comment: For //a[text()[normalize-space(.) = 'match text']] , this did not work when I tested with Selenium IDE (2.9.0). I had to remove the period - //a[text()[normalize-space() = 'match text']] - and then it identified the correct text.

Comment: @NoSuchElephantException Thanks for testing in Selenium (I don't have it installed, and not experienced using it). That would be valuable information.

Comment: No problem. I was a bit wrong, though! I did some more testing, and it looks like I may have mistyped your original expression. BOTH are turning up valid for me now: //a[text()[normalize-space(.) = 'match text']] and //a[text()[normalize-space() = 'match text']] - I am not sure which one is better, in theory, but if someone has trouble with one expression they might try the other.

Comment: @har07 I thought of marking this as answer as it is working in Xpath test. But this is not working in my browser

Answer (score 2):

A comment on all the answers: it's best to avoid using `text()`, because that makes it sensitive to comment nodes. Also, some (incorrect) XPath implementations fail to join adjacent text nodes, which can exist in a programmatically-constructed DOM. So it's always best to match the string value of the element, rather than the text nodes. And in any case, it's simpler. That makes the correct solution:

```
tbody/tr[@backcolor]/td/b/a[normalize-space(.) = 'match text']
```

Comment: This didn't worked. Thanks for the information regarding text()

Comment: The reason it didn't work is that  you've changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was already close.

If the 9000 match is the only not wanted match
try using **'not'** to exclude the 9000 match:

```
tbody/tr[@backcolor]/td/b/a[contains(text(), 'match text') and not (contains(text(), '9000'))]
```